# Javascript and Regex: undefined and ""

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am not really familiar with Regular Expressions and I am having the following problem:

When running the regExp to split my string I get lots of undefined and "" along with the result. I already tried to use "(?:" which I saw in another answer here in stackoverflow and lots of other things. 
I am then using the array.filter function to remove them but I didn`t want to do that. Can anyone help me? (and also explain to me why this is happening).

```
let values = line.split(/(\!=)|(<=)|(>=)|(==)|(\/\/)|(\/\*)|(\*\/)|(")|(=)|(<)|(>)|(\+)|(-)|(\*)|(\\)|(\()|(\))|;| /g);

return values.filter(value => {
    return value !== undefined && value !== "";
});
```

Strings that can be used:

```
"int x = 7;" => ["int","x","=","7",";"]

"int x = 7 + 25 * 52" => ["int","x","=","7","+","25","*","52"]

"while( x != 0)" => ["while","(","x","!=","0",")"]

'if(idade > 70 && sexo == "masculino")' 
    => ["if","(","idade",">","70","&&","sexo","==",""masculino"",")"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have each alternative in its own capture group. Only the capture group that actually matches will be filled in, the rest will be empty. Instead, put the capture group around all the alternatives.

```js
line = "#include <stdio.h>";
let values = line.split(/(\!=|<=|>=|==|\/\/|\/\*|\*\/|"|=|<|>|\+|-|\*|\\|\(|\)|;| )/g);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: I change it to: 

let values = line.split(/(\!=|<=|>=|==|\/\/|\/\*|\*\/|"|=|<|>|\+|-|\*|\\|\(|\)|;| )/g);

And i was specting it to return only the " " characters, but it is also returning "", do you know why this happens?

return value:
 ["#include", " ", "", "<", "stdio.h", ">", "", " ", ""]

Comment: If you have two delimiters in a row, it returns the empty string in between them. And if the string begins or ends with a delimiter, it returns the empty string before or after it.